# Why does inline-block cause div to disappear with Masonry?

Tags: jquery, html, css, masonry

I am using the Masonry isFitWidth approach on this page here: http://www.noidea.co.nz/products

Basically when I add `display: inline-block;` to the div with all the products in it it causes the div to disappear. It's really confusing as I am trying to use this method here: http://codepen.io/anon/pen/JYQNgv.

Or this code:

HTML

```
<div class="grid">
<div class="grid-item"></div>
<div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
<div class="grid-item grid-item--height3"></div>
<div class="grid-item grid-item--height2"></div>
<div class="grid-item"></div>
<div class="grid-item"></div>
<div class="grid-item"></div>
```

CSS

```
* {
    -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    font-family: sans-serif;
}
/* ---- grid ---- */

.grid {
    background: #EEE;
   /* center */

   margin: 0 auto;
}
/* clearfix */

.grid:after {
    content: '';
    display: block;
    clear: both;
}
/* ---- grid-item ---- */

.grid-item {
    width: 180px;
    height: 120px;
    float: left;
    background: #D26;
    border: 2px solid #333;
    border-color: hsla(0, 0%, 0%, 0.5);
    border-radius: 5px;
    padding-left: 5px;
    padding-right: 5px;
}  

.grid-item--height2 {
    height: 200px;
}

.grid-item--height3 {
    height: 260px;
}

</div>
```

JQUERY

```
// external js: masonry.pkgd.js

$(document).ready( function() {

    $('.grid').masonry({
        itemSelector: '.grid-item',
        columnWidth: 180,
        isFitWidth: true
    });

});
```

Cheers

Comment: Where are you putting it? in .grid? (struggling to recreate)

Comment: More to the point, what are you trying to achieve? Looking at the CodePen and the website, the CodePen is using Divs for the sub-containers, and your website is using UL/LI elements. Different html Elements are likely to behave differently.

Answer (score 1):

When you set display: inline-block to your grid container it loses the default width: 100% of the display: block; That happens because the grid items have position: absolute and thus are removed from the standard flow. If you want to use display: inline-block you have to set width: 100% or another desired fixed width like width: 980px like this:

```
.products_list {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100%;
}
```

Alternatively, you could remove the overflow:hidden, but I don't know how this will affect plugin's behavior.

```
.products_list {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: visible;
}
```